# How to display my elements with bootstrap in my case

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a responsive view for my app.

The problem here is the element numbers I need to display is dynamic.

For example

In my desktop, I want

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-10" ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.name}}  
    </div>
</div>
```

Lets say I have 13 products.
In desktop, I want

```
product 1 
product 2
product 3
product 4
product 5
product 6
product 7
product 8
product 9
product 10
product 11
product 12
product 13
```

In phone, I need

```
product 1 product 2 product 3 product 4 product 5 product 6 …etc
```

with a scroll bar.

The numbers of products are '`Dynamic`'.
I am not sure how to do this with bootstrap. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You want them in vertical order on desktop and horizontal on mobile? Cause I don't understand what you're trying to do else..

Comment: ng-repeat should not be on the col elements.. you only have a maximum of 12 grid columns you can use

Answer (score 0):

Assign them all the same `class="col-sm-12"` and they will arrange stacked on the desktop and have a scroll bar on mobile (viewing from top to bottom).  If you want to scroll left-right while the phone is held horizontally, that is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert them to a list, and use jQuery to set them to `inline` at a specific viewport size.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="items">
      <li>product 1</li>
      <li>product 2</li>
      <li>product 3</li>
      <li>product 4</li>
      <li>product 5</li>
      <li>product 6</li>
      <li>product 7</li>
      <li>product 8</li>
      <li>product 9</li>
      <li>product 10</li>
      <li>product 11</li>
      <li>product 12</li>
      <li>product 13</li>  
   </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    if($(window).width() > 768) {
        $('li').removeClass('inline');
    }else{
       $('li').addClass('inline');
    }
});
```

Example: [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/xwWwjZ)